# What is the process for baking on self generated account/keys?

Tags: tezos-client, baker, delegating, baking-node

I have the self-generated keys in Ubuntu server.

I don't want to use wallet that's why I used the command `tezos-client gen keys ACCOUNTNAME` to generate key and secret.

Now, I have successfully imported my account into system and I tried to register as a baker using the command `sudo -u tezos tezos-client register key testy12 as delegate` Which gives me an error:

```
Empty implicit contract (tz1NhTmL9AuetbQrAg3daigDoXcqx7K6ewA9)`.
```

where `tz1NhTmL9AuetbQrAg3daigDoXcqx7K6ewA9` is my pub key hash.

In order to register as a baker do I need to transfer 8k tez first in the pub key hash and then need to perform register command? let me know If I am missing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manager operations (which includes registering an account as a baker) cannot be applied to empty implicit accounts (empty in the sense of having no balance). So yes, you need to first reveal the account (send it some amount of tez so that it becomes non-empty).

Comment: okay I'll add some fund to the keys. Do i have to add fund in the address given keys_hashs file?

Comment: Send funds to your PKH (ie: the tz1)